# "Settings" is crashing after installing gapps

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, custom-roms, htc-desire-hd, google-apps

I've install custom rom called [JELLYTIME](https://code.google.com/p/jellytime/) on my HTC Desire HD phone. Recently I tried to update it to most recent version. After the update I installed google apps from this website: http://goo.im/gapps. I installed version 20130301. Since then the settings section works very badly. It crashes often and I can't connect to any wifi network for example. I'm afraid that I installed the wrong version of gapps but according to the table I should have installed that version for android 4.2.2. Can anyone please tell how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Did you wipe data/cache? If the answer is no, that would explain why settings is crashing (you were coming from a different ROM prior to this?).

Comment: Yes I tried it several times. I used the same ROM, just tried to upgrade it.

Comment: Used "*same ROM?*" What version was it prior to upgrade to 4.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why and how but in one case I solved this problem using wifix manager app. Just installed it and wifi started to work normally. Hope this helps anyone.

http://www.fardjad.com/android/wifix/